# Is there any way to get realtime output from shell script to website?

Tags: php, linux, laravel, shell, centos

I made a shell script to install web project on server when customer press a button on website.

I'm running command through the larval jobs

```
exec("/home/foldername/installation.sh
```

this shell script contains;

- creating folder
- creating database and import sql file
- creating virtual host for domain.(with sudo)
- restarting the web server. (with sudo)

Everything works. I want to show the realtime output of this shell script to the customer.
How can I achieve that?

I tried symphony process. but it is not allow me to run sudo httpd restart and creating files in the root folder.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `Symfony\Component\Process\Process` class to wrap your script and be able to set a callback to handle the real-time output. Combined to websocket broadcasting, you're able to show it on your website.

Here is the official documentation: https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/process.html#getting-real-time-process-output

Comment: How do you know he is using symfony? Not mentioned in his question.  This should be a comment IMHO.

Comment: I tried Symfony. sudo command not work

Comment: @Nic3500 he's using Laravel, so he automatically got Symfony classes in his `vendor` because Laravel is built upon Symfony

Comment: @Shizzen83 can I restart web server with Symfony process?

Comment: Depending on where you run this from, yes you could.

Comment: @Shizzen83: thanks for that, I did not know that detail.